# Python script for Parsing Office 365 HTML email and getting body

Tags: python-3.x

This is script to read email and parse body from outlook 365. For me does not work.
I have outlook 365 account without TFA. TFA is not activated

what could be a problem?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
 
from email.message import EmailMessage
import email
import imaplib
import re
import sys
import logging
import base64
import email.parser
import html2text
import requests
import json
import argparse
 
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-mpass', '-mailbox_password', dest = 'mailbox_password', help = 'mailbox password.')
args = parser.parse_args()
 
user = 'someuser@company.com'
mailbox_password ='Email Password' #args.mailbox_password
 
def get_email_body(body):
 
       if body.is_multipart():
         for payload in body.get_payload():
             print('To:\t\t', body['To'])
             print('From:\t', body['From'])
             print('Subject:', body['Subject'])
             print('Date:\t',body['Date'])
             for part in body.walk():
               if (part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain') and (part.get('Content-Disposition') is None):
                output = part.get_payload()
       else:
         print('To:\t\t', body['To'])
         print('From:\t', body['From'])
         print('Subject:', body['Subject'])
         print('Date:\t', body['Date'])
         print('Thread-Index:\t', body['Thread-Index'])
         text = f"{body.get_payload(decode=True)}"
         html = text.replace("b'", "")
         h = html2text.HTML2Text()
         h.ignore_links = True
         output = (h.handle(f'''{html}''').replace("\\r\\n", ""))
         output = output.replace("'", "")
         # output in one line
         #output = output.replace('\n'," ")
         output = output.replace('*', "")
         return output
 
def clear_inbox(conn, dest_folder):
    output=[]
    result = conn.uid('COPY', emailid, dest_folder)
    output.append(result)
    if result[0] == 'OK':
     result = mov, data = conn.uid('STORE',emailid, '+FLAGS', '(\Deleted Items)')
     conn.expunge()
 
conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("outlook.office365.com")
conn.login(user,mailbox_password)
conn.select("Inbox")
 
try:
 
  resp, items = conn.uid("search",None, 'All')
  items = items[0].split()
 
  for emailid in items:
   resp, data = conn.uid("fetch",emailid, "(RFC822)")
   if resp == 'OK':
     email_body = data[0][1].decode('utf-8')
     email_message = email.message_from_string(email_body)
     subject = email_message["Subject"]
     if subject.lower().startswith('Darktrace'.lower()):
         output = get_email_body(email_message)
 
         #do some task
         # move emails to Processed folder and clear Inbox
         clear_inbox(conn, "Processed")
     else:
        clear_inbox(conn, "backup")
 
except IndexError:
     print("No new email")
 
conn.close()
conn.logout()
```

This is error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "d:\python\lib\imaplib.py", line 1047, in _command_complete
typ, data = self._get_tagged_response(tag, expect_bye=logout)

File "d:\python\lib\imaplib.py", line 1173, in _get_tagged_response
self._get_response()

File "d:\python\lib\imaplib.py", line 1075, in _get_response
resp = self._get_line()

File "d:\python\lib\imaplib.py", line 1185, in _get_line
raise self.abort('socket error: EOF')

abort: socket error: EOF

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Dev Codes\ReadOutlookEmail.py", line 74, in 
resp, data = conn.uid("fetch", emailid, "(RFC822)")

File "d:\python\lib\imaplib.py", line 890, in uid
typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, command, *args)

File "d:\python\lib\imaplib.py", line 1230, in _simple_command
return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))

File "d:\python\lib\imaplib.py", line 1049, in _command_complete
raise self.abort('command: %s => %s' % (name, val))

abort: command: UID => socket error: EOF

Comment: Did you manage to do it?